# Accidentally enabled wireframe display, can't disable it

Tags: 3d-view, wireframe

I accidentally hit something on my keyboard and now I have these wireframe lines messing up my viewport.

[image: A screenshot of the Material Shading viewport, showing wireframe lines on a model]

Hitting Undo a bunch of times didn't fix the problem. How do I get these lines out of my viewport? I'm using Blender 2.81.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Wireframe* option can be deactivated in the *Viewport Overlay* settings.

[image: Viewport Overlay]

Comment: That was it! Can't believe I didn't find it. Thank you!